# Regex for finding possible words (scrabble-style)

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to create a "scrabble-solver" to run stress-tests on a scrabble-like game I'm developing. I have a database containing ~200.000 words and I'm now looking for a way to match the scrabble tiles given with the words in the database.

Example:

```
Given tiles: A, P, E, F, O, L, M

Result: APE, POLE, PALE, MOLE, PAL...
```

Is this possible by using a simple SELECT-statement with REGEXP? If possible I would also like to add letters on specific positions and be able to determine max/min length.

I hope this question made sense :)

I've been googling my eyes out but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. Anyone got an idea?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Hm, maybe not. Is there any other way to grab this from a MySQL-db, without regex?

Comment: It's fine to *store* your words in a relational database, but you'll probably want to load them into a more efficient data structure in memory for looking up combinations of letters.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like you should use a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't sound like a regex problem.  I think you'll be better off simply creating all possible combinations of letters from the existing tiles and then running your SELECT statement with the IN clause.  For example, with tiles:

```
A, P, E
```

your SELECT clause will be

```
SELECT word FROM words WHERE word IN ('APE', 'AEP', 'PAE' ,'PEA', 'EPA', 'EAP');
```

You'll get the list of valid words from your table.

Comment: Good idea! Just thinking, wouldn't this be kind of slow with 7 tiles or more?

Comment: With 7 tiles, you have 7! = 5040 combinations; so, yes, it may be a bit slow, however if you're only using this for testing your application, performance probably isn't the highest concern.

Comment: Assuming all letters are distinct (worst case scenario), we would get 13699 candidate words. With a lookup trie, that would make the algorithm sufficiently fast.

Answer (score 2):

A regex would not help you much in this case. You need to construct the possible words by yourself.

The problem is that you have a limited number of each possible letter and a regex cannot encode that information. If you had infinite supply of each letter, then you could use a regex like `[APEFOI]*`.

You will have to enumerate all the possible words yourself. The implementation would depend on the language your using, but your best bet might be a `next_permutation` function or better a function that enumerates all permutations. A simple (and slightly inefficient) implementation (in Python-like pseudocode) would be:

```
words = []
for permutation in permutations(letters): # enumerate all character orders
  for i in range(1, len(permutation)):    # enumerate all lengths of words
    words.append(letters[:i])             # append to candidate set
```

At that point `words` will contain all the candidate words you would then use in a `SELECT ... IN` statement.

That isn't the most efficient approach, but should be practical enough to get you started.